# Hide mail server's credentials in source

Tags: c#, .net, security

I have a desktop app, that send e-mail, using remote smtp-server. So in code I have smth like this:

```
string userName = "Alex";
string pass = "123456";
sendEmail(userName, pass);
```

Anyone, who reverse my app will have access to my mail-server. I wonder, is there any solutions to protect sensitive data (userName, pass) from reversing? Without obfuscating.

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: Suppose you do manage to do this. What are you going to do about the fact that since your code is running on someone else's machine, they can examine every single packet sent over the network, and get your mail server credentials that way?

Comment: @AakashM at least he will use a https connection anyway I think the problem is...to do not make it TOO easy.

Comment: @Adriano https doesn't help against an attacker *on the same machine*. But yes, I do agree that obfuscation can provide a first line of defence against casual attackers; I just want to make sure asker knows this can't be bullet-proof

Comment: Just out of curiosity, will your app be available for download?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your SMTP credentials and other sensitive data to app.config and make use of section encryption.

Answer (score 2):

If you supply a username and a password in your app, you should consider it exposed to the user - there is really no way to guarantee that the user does not examine your app or sniff the network connection.

Also, if is *common to block SMTP traffic* in firewalls and maintain a single smarthost, to avoid compromised machines becoming spambots. Even if you successfully manage to hide the credentials, using SMTP like this might be an unreliable choice.

You essentially have three options:

- Use the Send Email services of the OS - launching a mail in whatever email client the user has.
- Ask the user to configure a valid SMTP server.
- Set up your own relay to SMTP (for example as a *web service*), where you add additional checks and throttling to make sure it isn't misused.

The last option can of course be combined with authentication of the user against your own user database - that way you can shut down misbehaving users.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a webservice to send the email body which would in turn send the email to the recipient without exposing the user credentials to the client.  Even with obfuscation and encryption it would still be possible for someone to reverse engineer your application and gain access to your credentials.  Obfuscation is not security btw.

Comment: The question is: "I wonder, is there any solutions to protect sensitive data (userName, pass) from reversing?" Answer: Yes, don't store any account information in the client :)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried obfuscating you application? Try Dotfuscator Software Services to obfuscate your code and then see if it is able to hide/obfuscate the user name and password. Best option is to use app.config or web.config file to save your credentials with encryption or hash.

It is never a good practice to hard code credentials in the application.